# Mod Rewrite and java script popup

Tags: php, javascript, mod-rewrite, popup

Hello I am facing some issues with mod_rewrite applied to a javascript pop-up.
So this is my code for the rewrite part :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /popup.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But obviously is not working.
I am sure that mod_rewrite is working on the server because it's already working for joomla, and also I can see mod_rewrite loaded in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

This is my code for open the javascript popup

```
<script>

var newwindow;
function box(url)
{
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=640,width=750');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
</script>
```

...
...
...

```
<td><a href="javascript:box('/popup.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');">Click For Details</a> </font></td>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**LaterEdit:**

This is the content of my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /popup.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

What I really want to acomplish is :
http://www.example.com/popup/1.html or
http://www.example.com/1.html

With or without html it really doesn't matter, I just wanna get rid of the popup.php?id=1 part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to see how your htaccess matches your issue.

As far as I can see you try to catch urls sur as http://mysite/popup/foo/bar so they are rewritten to popup.php?foo=bar

If so you just need to add a [L] tag to your line

```
RewriteRule ^popup/(.*)/(.*)/$ /popup.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry the correct line is the first one i've posted in my question `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /popup.php?id=$1 [L]
` I've now re-edited my post in order to display the correct information from htaccess file

Comment: Well this seems to be a server specific issue. That's working as expected on my local machine. Have you tried to set it up on a devlopment server ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried now, and on dev. machine is working properly... Thanks a lot for your help